# Access a table in Databricks whose column name is numeric

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a file which doesn't have header.

So in turn, the dataframe I created got default headers (0,1,2,3)

For example, the following data frame:
`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)))`

And then I am converting this pandas df to the spark one:
`spdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)`

So this data frame has also the same column names (0,1,2,3)

After this, I am using to create the table (writing the df)
`spdf.write.saveAsTable('default.testX')`

Now this table, testX has headers 0,1,2,3 
As shown by `Describe testX`

But when I am doing `Select 1 from testX`
I am not able to access the column, and instead "1" is getting printed for the number of rows I have.

How can I tell the system that I am trying to access the columns.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please can you add workable code that can be debugged. Maybe add it all as a snippet it one go under your answer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer,

```
   select `0`, `1` from testx
```

That is wrapping the columns in ` symbol

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)),columns =[ 'col1', 'col2','col3', 'col4'])
spdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
spdf.show()
```

Use the column names to fetch the data that you need

Comment: I know , that at the time of creation itself I can add column names. But this random generated DF was an example. I will have files which will have Unknown number of columns . What can I do then?